# Как при открытии приложения устанавливать время в dateEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, datetime

Мне нужно при открытии приложения, чтобы время в `dateEdit` устанавливалось автоматически без нажатия кнопок, чтобы пользователю было легче и не приходилось вбивать каждый раз текущую дату.

```cpp
QDateTime *dateTime = new QDateTime;
ui->setupUi(this);
QTimer * timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(showTime()));
timer->start();
ui->dateEdit->setTime(QTime::currentTime());
```

Данный код работает так, что время будет обновляться по таймеру и выводиться в виджет (dateEdit).

Comment: Так и в чем, конкретно, вопрос?

Comment: Пример брал с учебника, только сделай таймер, но не работает, не пойму в чем дело...

Comment: не хватает `timer->setInterval(ms)`, а иначе откуда таймер знает через сколько времени сработать?

Comment: Я так полагаю, нужно реализовать слот showTime?

Comment: я вот так и не понимаю, его релизовывать как отдельную функцию? Мне просто нужен самый простой пример как выдавать текущую дату...

Comment: @Anton, чтобы понимать надо изучить https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html или http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.7.x/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Как функцию - член класса в секции slots или лямбда-функцию. И задать период обновления данных.  Или использовать single-shot, если обновлять нужно только при запуске приложения.